# Named router outlet causing 'Cannot match any routes' error in Angular 11 app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, router-outlet

I am using named router-outlet in Angular 11 app. The code in app.component.html file is

```html
    <ng-container *ngIf="showGeneric">
        <router-outlet name="general">
        </router-outlet>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="!showGeneric">
        <router-outlet name="non-general">
        </router-outlet>
    </ng-container>
```

The value of showGeneric is initially set to true in the app.component.ts file.

The code in app-routing.module.ts file is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NonGenericComponent } from './non-generic/main-component/non-generic.component';
import { GenericComponent } from './generic/main-component/generic.component';

 const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'generic',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 { 
   path: 'generic', 
   component: GenericComponent,
   loadChildren: () => import('./generic/generic.module').then(m => m.GenericModule),
   outlet: 'general'  
 },
 { 
   path: 'non-generic', 
   component: NonGenericComponent,
   loadChildren: () => import('./non-generic/non-generic.module').then(m => 
   m.NonGenericModule),
   outlet: 'non-general'  
 },
 {
   path: '**',
   redirectTo: 'generic',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 }
]

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When running the app locally and trying to navigate to http://localhost:4200/generic I am getting **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'generic'.** I couldn't figure out what exactly is causing the issue. Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried without the loadChildren property ?

Comment: Generic module depends on third party modules like ng-bootstrap. If I remove loadChildren property, an error is thrown that dependencies are missing.

Comment: well it seems that when you pass an outlet, the route object only accept a component (not a child module). Did you try import your third-party dependencies in this current module ?

Comment: The loadChildren property specifies the module that needs to be used when loading that component. In above case it specifies GenericModule needs to be used. So third party dependencies are imported into GenericModule. The parent module for GenericModule is AppModule itself. Do you mean I should import third party dependencies into AppModule?

Comment: seems like there is a workaround : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12842#issuecomment-270836368

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @mJehanno there is no need for named router outlet to achieve this functionality

Remove the named router outlets and simply pass children routes to the router config to load this module

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'generic',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'generic',
    component: GenericComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./generic/generic.module').then(m => m.GenericModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'non-generic',
    component: NonGenericComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./non-generic/non-generic.module').then(
            m => m.NonGenericModule
          )
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'generic',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

In the html

```html
<a [routerLink]='["generic"]'>Generic</a> |
<a [routerLink]='["non-generic"]'>Non Generic</a> | 

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[Sample Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62zbez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (Check console)